# convert array into given type of array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of type:-

```
const arr = ['abc','def','ghi'];
```

but I want this array in the form of

```
const arr2 = [
    {value: 'abc'},
    {value: 'def'},
    {value: 'ghi'},
];
```

I am not getting the idea to do it.

Comment: simple for do with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Show what you tried, its a simple loop

Comment: Voting to reopen since this question is clear and focused, but perhaps I'm missing something. Would those who chose to close this because it "_needs to be more focused_" care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a map function to generate a new array with the type you want

for your reference, [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr=['abc','def','ghi'];
const arr2 = arr.map(item => ({value: item}));
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var arr = ['abc','def','ghi'];
arr = arr.map(value => ({value}));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to transform each item of an array to another value.

```js
const arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];

const arr2 = arr.map(value => ({ value: value })

// const arr2 = [
//   { value: "abc" },
//   { value: "def" },
//   { value: "ghi" }
// ];
```

If you want to be clever you can simplify this to

```js
const arr2 = arr.map(value => ({ value })
```

See `Array.prototype.map`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way that I prefer:

```
Array.from(arr, (v) => {return {value: v};})
```